# Sql query result structure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I need to know query result structure . Let's say i have this query :

```
SELECT T.name as names 
FROM (SELECT name,sex FROM user) T
WHERE T.sex='male'
```

What i need to know is the structure of the result of this query , something like this :

```
column_name : names TYPE : varchar(60)
```

Is there a way to get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a bit complicated to do.  One method that works across databases is to do the following:

- Create a table or view with the structure
- Investigate the metadata

In MySQL, you can do:

```
create table temp_table as
    select t.name as names
    from (select name, sex from user) t
    where t.sex = 'male'
    limit 0;
```

This should create an empty table with the right columns.  You can then look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the information you want.

In MySQL, a temporary table is preferable to a view, because (older versions of) MySQL severely limit the queries that can be used for views.

Answer (score 1):

First create a `view`

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
SELECT T.name as names FROM
(SELECT name,sex FROM user) T
WHERE    T.sex='male'
```

Then simply run a `desc` or `describe` on the `view` like

```
desc view_name
```

You can get the result of this query using your code and use it as you need.

Comment: The problem is that it's not allowed to create views on nested selects

Answer (score 0):

At place where you make a request you know a tables and columns that you request. Than you can make a query to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and receive descriptions of needed columns

like

```
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
        [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
        [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
```

[21.4 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create a view to get your table structure just execute following command

```
 describe table_name
```

or 
`desc table_name`